# Switch based on addEventListener from Select tag not working

Tags: javascript, forms, switch-statement, html-select, addeventlistener

I`m trying to validate text inputs from a form to build a base converter using javascript and Jquery. With addEventListener function I was able to call a switch case that corresponds to options "2", "10" and "16" from the Select tag.

The problem is that it is only working for the first "change" event on the Select tag and when I decrease from bases. For example: If I select base 2 and then change to 10 or 16, it still only accepts 0 or 1 characters while changing from 16 to 10 or 2 it works fine. How can i fix it?

Here is my Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getFromBase = document.getElementById('frombase-select');

  getFromBase.addEventListener('change', function() {
    switch (getFromBase.value) {
      case '2':
        $('#number').keypress(function(key) {
          if ((key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 49) && (key.charCode != 13)) {
            return false;
          }
        });
        break;

      case '10':
        $('#number').keypress(function(key) {
          if ((key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) && (key.charCode != 13)) {
            return false;
          }
        });
        break;

      case '16':
        $('#number').keypress(function(key) {
          if ((key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) && (key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 102) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 70) && (key.charCode != 13)) {
            return false;
          }
        });
        break;
    } // End switch
  }); // End addEventListener
}); // End document.ready
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

form>* {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group flex-center">
      <label>From Base:</label>
      <select id="frombase-select" name="frombase">
        <option selected disabled hidden>Enter a base</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>16</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group flex-center">
      <label>Number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="number" name="number">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are attaching an additional `.keypress()` event to `#number` element at each `change` event of `#frombase-select` element

Comment: Thanks. That certainly made the code cleaner. Heres is an update with your recomendation:
http://codepen.io/guizo/pen/ORByaQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event handlers are piling up. You never reset the handlers thus the validation for the first selected base is never unbound. This causes the event to only trigger the first selected case's callback.

You may use [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the previous handlers. From the documentation:

> *Description*: Remove an event handler.
>
> **`.off( event )`**
>
> **event**
>
> Type: Event
>
> A `jQuery.Event` object.

You can just pass in the event name as a string to remove the event handler. Demonstration [`off`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handlers:

```
$("#number").off("keypress"); //Callback is optional
```

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/2o63xmc7/1/) an updated fiddle.

Comment: @guizo - make sure to review the edits I've made to discourage deprecated methods.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the issue. But I still don't understand why changing from a bigger base to a smaller worked even though the event were not unbinded.

Comment: @guizo It shouldn't. Since you set an event handler on your first select, and never reset it - it should never work for any of the others except the first selected.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with review the edits. I use Stack Overflow a lot but I rarely ask questions. What should I do?

Comment: @guizo Nevermind :), if you've got any other questions, I'll be glad to help